# What size of hutch would be right for two mini lops?

Tags: rabbits, containment, introducing-pets, cage

*Warning, I am completely new to owning rabbits! Have had guinea pigs/hamsters in the past but no rabbits.*

I am interested in buying two mini lop rabbits and  have a large garden but a small budget. What would be the best sized hutch for them that is not too expensive? Would it be OK to just have a run with a little sheltered bit for them? Also have two dogs so living indoors isn't really an option, any ideas?

*ALSO*

If i were to get two rabbits that had already bonded, i.e from the same family, would i need to get them spayed/neutered or will they not fight as they get older? If they are spayed/neutered how would i look after them when they got home (for ex. would i split them up for a few days?)

*ALSO*

What medical needs do they have? found bits and bobs of their needs on the internet but nothing was particularly clear to me.

Many thanks,

Anon.

Comment: For medical needs it depends what part of the world you are from, where are you located?

Comment: You have several questions in one here.  Most of which we already have multiple answers to, You can surf [all of our rabbit questions and answers here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits)  also see [bucks and does](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6581) and read about [outdoor rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2769)